# Did Google recently change UI to grant public access to bucket objects in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Ok, I've been using Google Cloud Platform for some video files
that are are viewable from a few web pages I built. I started this two or three years ago, and I have loved it.

But, now it appears they broke it, without warning/telling us.

So, in the platform's console, yesterday (for first time since a month or two ago), I uploaded another video...that part went fine.  But, when it came time to click on the checkbox to grant public access, the checkbox is now GONE. (The only part of the UI that looks NEW,
is the column labeled 'public access'.  Instead of just a check-box to toggle on or off, now there's a yellow-triangle and an oval-shaped symbol. Once or twice, I was able to get a popup to appear saying 'edit permission', but that quickly led into the weeds.)

After half an hour or so, I finally thought to call platform support, and explained my problem to a guy (with just enough Australian accent to cause me to have to ask for repeats quite a bit...sigh).

So, they logged me a case# and I suggested I was headed to bed, and asked that we now use email (rather than the phone) to continue. Just before bed, I got the case#, and a query about whether it was ok for them to 'change my console'.  I replied to the email, saying yes, and went to bed.)

So that was last nite.  This morning, re-reading their email, it seems to say that it could be 3 or 4 days, before a more technical person will contact me.

Some re-reading their platform-console docs, I'm now GUESSING that maybe they just nuked the public-access checkbox, and that now I'm supposed to spend hours (days?) taking a short-course on IAM-permmissions, and learn some new long-winded method.

(This whole mess could have been avoided, if they'd just emailed us an informational warning of this UI-change, with some new 5-step short list or tutorial of how to learn to use their 'new, much more complicated,
way to specify public-access'.  From where I sit, this change is equivalent to Microsoft saying 'instead of that checkbox, you'll need to learn to make registry edits...see our platform docs on how to do that.)

Right now, I have more than half-a-mind, to seriously consider bailing out of Google's cloud storage, and consider switching to one of the others.  But, I'm not quite ready yet, to make that jump (from the frying-pan into the fire?).  :^)

Anyone else been down this road?  What meeting did I miss?  Is there a quicker way out of my dilemma, than just waiting for Google-support to get back to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [the change you mention](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/release-notes#july_18_2018) was introduced on July 18th. I’m not sure why, but judging by the change description, it looks like it is aimed to avoid accidentally making sensitive information public: “Objects can no longer be made public through one-click actions”.

You can find the procedure to make a single object public [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects). It can be achieved through the Console and won't take you more than a few minutes. Once the object is shared publicly, you can use the icon in the “public access” column  to get the URL for the object.

You can also [make all the content of a bucket public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets) using a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload your objects into a bucket, you can upload with ACL as publicRead
and all your objects will have public URL.

```
public async Task UploadObjectAsync(string bucketName, string objectName, Stream source, string contentType = "image/jpeg")
        {
            var storage = StorageClient.Create();
            await storage.UploadObjectAsync(bucketName, objectName, contentType, source, new UploadObjectOptions()
            {
                PredefinedAcl = PredefinedObjectAcl.PublicRead
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected.  (I still wonder if they even considered sending an email to each registered/existing customer.)

Ok, yes, (finally, after some practices), this solves it!  Thx for those two answers.

(But in my view, their UI-change is still a work-in-progress)  So, I have a SUGGESTION for ya, Google. Once one is into the permissions-edit-dialog, and remembers to do an 'add', there's are the 3 fields.  The first and third are fine...drop-downs with choices. But that middle entry needs work...how about doing something like an auto-guess-ahead...initialize the field to a suggested value of 'allUsers', so we don't have to remember what to type and how to spell it, or something along those lines.

EDIT: [Actually, it ought to be possible to make that field a drop-down-list choice, with 'allUsers' as one suggested value, and a second value as a text-entry (for specific user-names, etc).]

Comment: If you want to submit this suggestion to Google's Issue Tracker you can use [this form](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=1010944). Advantages: Other users can  vote for your feature request. If it is feasible for Google Engineers to work on it, you can keep track of the progress.

Comment: Great idea, Mike...thx for making me aware.  So, I filed such an issue-tracker request here:   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113342107

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [8 Ball Pool](https://8ballpool.onl/) it is not possible to list files [Google Hangouts](https://googlehangouts.ooo/) without access to the [Omegle](https://omegle.onl/) bucket that contains them. This is due to the current design of the library, which requires that the bucket is loaded before listing its files.